# how to pivot a dataframe by unique ID, so that binary columns remains the same?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

My problem is that I can not convert this:

```
import pandas as pd

example = {
"ID": [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3],
"place":["Maryland","Maryland", "Washington", "Washington", "Washington", "Los Angeles"],
"sex":["male","male","female", "female", "female", "other"],
"depression": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
"stressed":  [1 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
"sleep": [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
"ate":[0,1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
}

#load into df:
example = pd.DataFrame(example)

print(example)
```

[image]

to this:

```
import pandas as pd

result = {
"ID": [1, 2, 3],
"place":["Maryland","Washington","Los Angeles"],
"sex":["male", "female", "other"],
"depression": [0, 0, 1],
"stressed":  [1,0,0],
"sleep": [1, 1, 1],
"ate":[1, 1 , 1],
}

#load into df:
result = pd.DataFrame(result)

print(result)
```

[image]

I was trying to pivot it like this:

```
table = example.pivot_table(index='place',columns='ID')  
print (table)
```

However, it looks totally different and I am confused how to set values for it. Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear how the expected result is related to the given input. For example, why is the `stressed` value for `Los Angeles` not `1`?

Comment: I attached the wrong screenshot, I am sorry. Now, I updated the question. In general, it is 1 if a person was stressed at least one time,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `any` to get there:

```
example.groupby(['ID','place','sex']).any().astype(int).reset_index()

   ID        place     sex  depression  stressed  sleep  ate
0   1     Maryland    male           0         1      1    1
1   2   Washington  female           0         0      1    1
2   3  Los Angeles   other           1         0      1    1
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html) (which acts as a logical OR on 1/0 values) as an aggregation function:

```py
example.groupby(['ID', 'place','sex']).max().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   ID        place     sex  depression  stressed  sleep  ate
0   1     Maryland    male           0         1      1    1
1   2   Washington  female           0         0      1    1
2   3  Los Angeles   other           1         0      1    1
```

Answer (score 0):

The default aggregation function is mean, to keep it binary, use `aggfunc='max'`:

```
table = example.pivot_table(index='place', columns='ID', aggfunc=np.max, fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
            stressed        
ID                 1  2  3  
place                       
Los Angeles        0  0  0  
Maryland           1  0  0  
Washington         0  0  0
```

Although in your case you might want a `Groupby.max`:

```
example.groupby(['ID', 'place', 'sex'], as_index=False).max()
```

Output:

```
   ID        place     sex  depression  stressed  sleep  ate
0   1     Maryland    male           0         1      1    1
1   2   Washington  female           0         0      1    1
2   3  Los Angeles   other           1         0      1    1
```